# Google font acting up?

Tags: html, google-font-api

So this is my syntax (just a clip)

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div style="background-color:black;width:auto">
    <div style="width:1000px; margin:0 auto;">
        <table style="width:1000px;">
                <td><p align="right"><h1 style="color:white;font-family:Exo"> When strategy meets chance, champions born</h1></p></td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, nothing should go wrong right?

[image]

But here's a funny thing when I block it.
[image]

It shows the right text!

WHY?

(And as you can see, not all text is effected)

Comment: maybe wrong file encoding in your html file?

Comment: There's no unicode in the file.

Comment: The clip in the question does not reproduce the problem (tested on Firefox, Chrome, IE). Whatever is causing the phenomenon is somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

You set style about:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100italic,100,200italic,200,300italic,300,400italic,400,500italic,500,600italic,600,700italic,700,800italic,800,900italic,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Emphasis please. How this simple code fixes or explain the issue, and I don't to load a lot of font. It will load my website heavily.

Comment: The answer does not address the problem asked. It does address a different problem, though: when you use a font inside an `h1` element and you are not overriding the default bold font weight, you should include a bold (700) typeface. Otherwise, you will get the regular typeface as algorithmically bolded, which is typographically inferior.